# "stop" method isn't working for an image element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

HTML:

```
<img src="image/heli.png"  class = "heli">

<script src="jquery/game.js" ></script>
```

jQuery:

```
var hel = $('.heli');
fly();

function fly()
{

    hel.animate({top :'-=25px' ,left :'+=25px'},800,CollisonCheck)

}

function CollisonCheck()
{
    var tp =$(this).offset().top;
    var lft = $(this).offset().left;

    if (((tp>=365) && (tp<=610)) && ((lft>=241) && (lft<=370)))
    {
        stop_game();
    }
}

function stop_game()
{
    hel.stop();
}
```

When I run this code, the `stop()` method is not working. Console also doesn't give any error.

What is the error in this code? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Try `hel.stop(true, true);`

Comment: @mplungjan-Actually i want to stop the animation when necessary condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CollisonCheck` function will only be called after the animation has completed therefore `stop()` would do nothing(since it has already stopped). You'll have to call `` on some kind of interval

```
function fly()
{
  hel.animate({top :'-=25px' ,left :'+=25px'},800)
  setInterval(CollisonCheck, 50);
}

function CollisonCheck()
{
  var tp = hel.offset().top;
  var lft = hel.offset().left;
  if (((tp>=365) && (tp<=610)) && ((lft>=241) && (lft<=370)))
  {
    stop_game();
  }
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution of "stop" method for my code.Just Write "$fx.off = true" instead of stop().

```
function stop_game()
{
$fx.off = true;
}
```